# How to use the constructor? java

Tags: java, constructor

```
    package aprilchap3;

/**
 *
 * @author ericaross
 */

public class SavingsAccount {
    double interest;
    double balance;

 public SavingsAccount() {
    balance = 0;
    interest = 0.1;
}
 public void addInterest() {
     balance = interest*balance + balance;
}
 public void deposit(double amount) {
     balance= balance + amount;
 }
 public void getBalance(){
     return balance;
 }
}
```

``and this is the SavingsAccountTester class:

```
    package aprilchap3;


    /**
     *
     * @author ericaross
     */
    public class SavingAccountTester {
      public static void main(String[] args)  {
      SavingsAccount erica = new SavingsAccount();


erica.deposit(1000);
  erica.addInterest();
  Double ericaBalance = erica.getBalance()  ;


System.out.println(ericaBalance + "this is how much you owe. ");`

          }
        }
```

So the problem is that I want to use the constructor to set the value instead of depositing, but when I try to do it an error shows up in Savings Account declaration.
here is where I want to put it  `SavingsAccount erica = new SavingsAccount();` but an error shows up every time can any one show me the best way to set constructor to work?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Your constructor takes no parameters.  I dont understand what you expected?

Comment: `public void getBalance(){` is decalred as `void` so it can't not return a value, either remove `return balance;` or, as I think you want it, change it to `public double getBalance(){`

Comment: What is the error you are getting while using the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public SavingsAccount() {
    balance = 0;
    interest = 0.1;
}
```

You don't need this. You could have made those the initial values of the variables. What you need is

```
public SavingsAccount(double balance, double interest) {
    this.balance = balance;
    this.interest = interest;
}
```

and you then use it via `new SavingsAcccount(balance, interest)`.

NB I hope and trust this is homework. You should never ever ever use floating-point datatypes for money.

Comment: I can only suggest you read my answer again, or remove your comment if it is now obsolete. The code in your comment is not the code in my answer.